# How to install plugins into Qt Designer?

Tags: qt, pyqt, pyqt4, qt-creator, qt-designer

I have scoured the internet for information regarding the installation process for plugins into Qt Designer and I have found no helpful/relevant information.

The plugin I want to install is the echo plugin.

I have also looked through the Qt Designer program files and found the echoplugin folder but have no idea how to install it. Here is the file location:

C:\Qt\Examples\Qt-5.5\widgets\tools\echoplugin

This holds the following file types; Qt Project Files, C++ Header, C++ Source and JSON

**System Information**

Windows 10

PyQt4

Qt Designer 5.5.0

Comment: https://wiki.python.org/moin/PyQt/Using_Python_Custom_Widgets_in_Qt_Designer

Answer (score 1):

[Official documentation](http://doc.qt.io/qtcreator/adding-plugins.html#locating-qt-designer-plugins) describes it very well.

To install plugin for *Qt Designer* or *Qt Creator* you need to place the plugin to *plugins\designer* directory.

For *Qt Creator* it is located in it's *bin* directory.

*Qt Designer* is a part of Qt installation so directory will be *QTDIR\plugins\designer* where *QTDIR* is Qt installation path (for me it is "E:\DEV\Qt\5.5\msvc2015_desktop_shared" and full plugins path is "E:\DEV\Qt\5.5\msvc2015_desktop_shared\plugins\designer").

**One important thing** - *Qt Designer* / *Qt Creator* and the plugin must be compiled using the same compiler version. You can not install plugin compiled with MSVC 2015 to *Qt Designer* compiled with MSVC 2013!

**Edit:**

I am using C++ version of Qt.

It looks like *echo plugin* is not a plugin for *Qt Designer* / *Qt Creator*.

Comment: Then why is the echo plugin there? Even Qt has the download for it on there site